# if x > 0 but less than y

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

Sorry for kind of stupid question.

I use an UITextField, where I can enter some numbers.

No i use this code to detect if the entered number is 0, greater than 0, and less than 15.

```
if (myNr <= 15){
NSLog (@"the number is OK");

}
else if (myNr > 15)
{
NSLog(@"this number doesn't existing");
}
else if (myNr == 0)
{
NSLog(@"number should be between 1 and 15");
}
```

I got some errors when the number is 0.

i Need to be able to insert numbers only between 1 and 15, if the number is 0 or greater then 15, NSLog should say.

thanks

Comment: basically, your code does work because 0 <= 15 is true, and the first statement executes first therefore you get `the number is OK`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should put `if(myNr == 0)` at first

```
if (myNr == 0)
{
 NSLog(@"number should be between 1 and 15");
} else if (myNr <= 15)
{
  NSLog (@"the number is OK");

}
else if (myNr > 15)
{
   NSLog(@"this number doesn't existing");
}
```

Comment: @user2805816 let me know if you have any problem

Answer (score 0):

What error do you get?

Offhand, remember: Capitalization matters. `NSLog` is different than `nslog`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code reduces to:

```
if (myNr <= 15)
{
   NSLog(@"the number is OK");
}
else
{
   NSLog(@"this number doesn't existing");
}
```

The case for 0 is never reached.

Remember the tests are considered sequentially.